# Special characters in Lua variable

Tags: variables, lua, character, native

I'm using Lua and I want to use a so called "native variable" that will be read-only and they will be recognized with a "$" mark in front of them e.g. $variable. But in what I've found Lua only accepts normal alphabetic characters and underscore as variable names. Is there some way that I can modify the Lua code to do this?

Comment: You could modify the meta table to stop accepting changes to variables and that would be an easy way to implement this. Like: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ReadOnlyTables or if this works for you: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lua%20read%20only%20variables&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Flua-users.org%2Flists%2Flua-l%2F2002-01%2Fmsg00402.html&ei=p9gRUPemHsfeiALtrICADg&usg=AFQjCNGXfMula1LA1howLMMhNcZdJKx-LQ

Comment: why don't you just use a configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

consider pre-processing your lua source to replace `$identifier` with `__NATIVE.identifier` using a simple parser, then send the modified source to a regular lua interpreter. Then implement __NATIVE to be a global table with the appropriate metatable to implement your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use metatables to prevent a variable from being altered. The Lua source is free under MIT, which is permissive enough for virtually any use, but I have no specific advice on how you can modify it to allow `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to use special characters in the Lua language:

See here: http://lua.gts-stolberg.de/en/Variablen.php

Comment: The URL is broken.